# Fill between two arcs in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide, fill

I have six arcs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){a}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){b}
\tkzDefPoint(4,10){c}

\tkzInterCC[R](a,6cm)(b,8cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{AB1} \tkzGetSecondPoint{AB2}
\tkzInterCC[R](a,6cm)(c,6cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{AC1} \tkzGetSecondPoint{AC2}
\tkzInterCC[R](b,8cm)(c,6cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{BC1} \tkzGetSecondPoint{BC2}

\tkzDrawArc(a,AB2)(AB1)
\tkzDrawArc(b,AB1)(AB2)

\tkzDrawArc(a,AC2)(AC1)
\tkzDrawArc(c,AC1)(AC2)

\tkzDrawArc(b,BC2)(BC1)
\tkzDrawArc(c,BC1)(BC2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I want to fill the three lenses formed by these arcs.

If I use `\tkzFillSector`, it fills the sector of the circle completely:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

What is the easiest way to fill inside this lens?

Comment: You could use clip and please post an MWE.

Comment: +1 for the MWE! I just checked, you an simply append the scopes from my code and the shadings are done correctly.

Comment: @marmot That is exactly what I've done. Works like a charm :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a lot of effort for this output. You only need plain Ti*k*Z for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (12,0);
\coordinate (c) at (4,10);
\begin{scope}
\clip (a) circle (6cm);
\fill[blue!40!white] (b) circle (8cm);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (c) circle (6cm);
\fill[blue!40!white] (b) circle (8cm);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (c) circle (6cm);
\fill[blue!40!white] (a) circle (6cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is a possible way to compute the intersections.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (12,0);
\coordinate (c) at (4,10);
\begin{scope}
\clip[name path global=CircleA] (a) circle (6cm);
\fill[name path global=CircleB,blue!40!white] (b) circle (8cm);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip[name path global=CircleC] (c) circle (6cm);
\fill[blue!40!white] (b) circle (8cm);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (c) circle (6cm);
\fill[blue!40!white] (a) circle (6cm);
\end{scope}
\path[name intersections={of=CircleA and CircleB, name=AB}];
\fill (AB-1) circle (1pt);\fill (AB-2) circle (1pt);
\path[name intersections={of=CircleA and CircleC, name=AC}];
\fill (AC-1) circle (1pt);\fill (AC-2) circle (1pt);
\path[name intersections={of=CircleB and CircleC, name=BC}];
\fill (BC-1) circle (1pt);\fill (BC-2) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a great answer and just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Can I somehow determine the intersection points of circles?

Comment: @padawan Yes. With the intersection library. BTW, I have not tried, but quite likely you only need to append the three scopes from my answer to your code to do the filling. (I could not check because you did not provide an [MWE].)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same code with `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\[htbp\]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\[scale=0.3\]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){a}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){b}
\tkzDefPoint(4,10){c}

\tkzInterCC\[R\](a,6cm)(b,8cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{AB1} \tkzGetSecondPoint{AB2}
\tkzInterCC\[R\](a,6cm)(c,6cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{AC1} \tkzGetSecondPoint{AC2}
\tkzInterCC\[R\](b,8cm)(c,6cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{BC1} \tkzGetSecondPoint{BC2}

\tkzDrawArc(a,AB2)(AB1)
\tkzDrawArc(b,AB1)(AB2)

\tkzDrawArc(a,AC2)(AC1)
\tkzDrawArc(c,AC1)(AC2)

\tkzDrawArc(b,BC2)(BC1)
\tkzDrawArc(c,BC1)(BC2)

\begin{scope}
\tkzClipSector(b,BC2)(BC1)
\tkzFillSector\[blue!40!white\](c,BC1)(BC2)
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\tkzClipSector(a,AB2)(AB1)
\tkzFillSector\[blue!40!white\](b,AB1)(AB2)
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\tkzClipSector(a,AC2)(AC1)
\tkzFillSector\[blue!40!white\](c,AC1)(AC2)
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]